# Shims for Class not generating (MSFakes)

Tags: .net, xunit

Hi I added fakes for one of my class library project .
There are two classes in that project .I get Stubs and Shims for one of the class in that project but not for the 2nd class. 
For the second class I only get the Stubs and not the Shims .
I tried various workarounds like in the .Fakes xml file I added  tags but it was of no help .
Kindly help 
I am using .net framework 4.6.1